# Crear carta de restaurante a partir de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json

estoy tratando de hacer un menú de un restaurante a partir de este JSON:

```
[
    {
        "category": "Carnes",
        "code": "meat_plates",
        "content": [
            {
                "plate": "Solomillo taburete",
                "specification": "Muy poco hecho",
                "price": "18",
                "allergen": [
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1_VNClN6qKBg002OSrxGk2yzFrTvdSMwk",
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1GdNpiOXj_AhMKTw8i1E5O2AhSxPNoV1s",
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1OOT_U5DaVOySKYrrtpZqnpqDDM8R10e4"
                ]
            },
            {
                "plate": "Solomillo con bacon y setas",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "18",
                "allergen": [
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1GdNpiOXj_AhMKTw8i1E5O2AhSxPNoV1s",
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1OOT_U5DaVOySKYrrtpZqnpqDDM8R10e4"
                ]
            },
            {
                "plate": "Solomillo con manzana frita",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "18",
                "allergen": []
            },
            {
                "plate": "Chulet\u00f3n de Cantabria con pimiento",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "20",
                "allergen": []
            },
            {
                "plate": "San Jacobo",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "15",
                "allergen": [
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1_VNClN6qKBg002OSrxGk2yzFrTvdSMwk",
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1I9e6-tckM-zk7VZPTpQo9WcYD4utjFLM"
                ]
            },
            {
                "plate": "Filete de ternera a la plancha",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "12",
                "allergen": []
            },
            {
                "plate": "Lomo de cerdo a la plancha",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "12",
                "allergen": []
            },
            {
                "plate": "Escalope",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "12",
                "allergen": [
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1_VNClN6qKBg002OSrxGk2yzFrTvdSMwk",
                    "https:\/\/drive.google.com\/uc?id=1I9e6-tckM-zk7VZPTpQo9WcYD4utjFLM"
                ]
            },
            {
                "plate": "Chulet\u00f3n de vaca vieja a la plancha con parrillada vegetal",
                "specification": "Plato especial",
                "price": "24",
                "allergen": []
            },
            {
                "plate": "",
                "specification": "",
                "price": "3",
                "allergen": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

(El JSON es muy largo, ahorro el código poniendo una sola categoría pero hay 8 categorías, algunas con 20 platos, otras con 2, dependiendo de lo que sea, ya que si lo pongo entero la pregunta sumaría 33.000 líneas).

Hice un modelo primero para ver cómo me gustaría que quedase, teniendo en cuenta que es una estructura un tanto compleja, me está dando bastantes problemas.
El ejemplo de cómo me gustaría que quedase sería así:

[image: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda]

Contando con que las categorías con pocos platos solo tendría una columna, yo puse el límite en 5 platos, si tiene más, deberían tener tres columnas.

Hasta ahora lo que he conseguido hacer es esto, pero totalmente infructuoso, es muchísimo código repetido, pero no me hago una idea de cómo puedo mejorarlo, ya que debo tener en cuenta en qué situaciones quiero hacer una o tres columnas, en qué situaciones tengo un número que no es múltiplo de 3 para poder poner los platos como en la imagen de muestra (6 platos en la primera columna, 5 platos en la segunda, 6 en la tercera).

A parte de repetir el código, hago que siempre saque el mismo plato repetido X número de veces por columna. El problema es a la hora de iterar, hago un Hadōken o bien lo hago directamente mal

Aquí muestro mi galimatías:

```
fetch('http://localhost/restaurante-la-cena/connect.php')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => doMenu(data));

function doMenu(data){
    data.forEach(element => {
      makingCategory(element);   
    });
}

function makingCategory(category){
  
  // inicializar elementos  
  let sec_work        = document.createElement("section");
  let content         = document.createElement("div");
  let h2              = document.createElement("h2");
  let column_content  = document.createElement("div");

  // agregar atributos
  sec_work            .setAttribute("class", "sec work");
  sec_work            .setAttribute("id", category.code);
  content             .setAttribute("class", "content");
  column_content      .setAttribute("class", "column-content");

  // rellenar titulos
  h2.innerHTML        = category.category;

  // appends
  document.body       .append(sec_work);
  sec_work            .append(content);
  content             .append(h2);    
  content             .append(column_content);

  // iteraciones por categoria
  // filtro categoria length
  let cat_len           = category.content.length;
  let plates_per_column = Math.floor(cat_len/3);
  let rest_of_plates    = cat_len%3;

 if(cat_len <= 5){
   console.log("Hacer solo una columna");

    let column = document.createElement("div");
    column.setAttribute("class", "column");
    column_content.append(column);

    for(let i = 0; i < cat_len; i++){
      let plate = document.createElement("div");
      plate.setAttribute("class", "plate");
      column.append(plate);

      let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
      h3.innerHTML = category.content[i].plate;
      plate.append(h3);

      let alergen = document.createElement("div");
      alergen.setAttribute("class", "alergen");
      plate.append(alergen);

      for(let a = 0; a < category.content[i].allergen.length; a++){
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", category.content[i].allergen[a]);
        alergen.append(img);
      }

      let prize = document.createElement("div");
      prize.setAttribute("class", "prize");
      plate.append(prize);

      let label = document.createElement("label");
      label.setAttribute("for", "prize");
      label.innerHTML = parseFloat(category.content[i].price).toFixed(2)+"€";
      prize.append(label);
    }

 } else {
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    let column = document.createElement("div");
    column.setAttribute("class", "column");
    column_content.append(column);

    for(let j = 0; j < (plates_per_column); j++){
      if(i == 1){
        
        for(let k = 0; k < rest_of_plates; k++){
          let plate = document.createElement("div");
          plate.setAttribute("class", "plate");

          let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
          h3.innerHTML = category.content[i].plate;
          plate.append(h3);

          let alergen = document.createElement("div");
          alergen.setAttribute("class", "alergen");
          plate.append(alergen);

          for(let a = 0; a < category.content[i].allergen.length; a++){
            let img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src", category.content[i].allergen[a]);
            alergen.append(img);
          }

          let prize = document.createElement("div");
          prize.setAttribute("class", "prize");
          plate.append(prize);

          let label = document.createElement("label");
          label.setAttribute("for", "prize");
          label.innerHTML = parseFloat(category.content[i].price).toFixed(2)+"€";
          prize.append(label);

          column.insertBefore(plate, column.childNodes[0]);
        }
      } else {
        let plate = document.createElement("div");
        plate.setAttribute("class", "plate");

        let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
        h3.innerHTML = category.content[i].plate;
        plate.append(h3);

        let alergen = document.createElement("div");
        alergen.setAttribute("class", "alergen");
        plate.append(alergen);

        for(let a = 0; a < category.content[i].allergen.length; a++){
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.setAttribute("src", category.content[i].allergen[a]);
          alergen.append(img);
        }

        let prize = document.createElement("div");
        prize.setAttribute("class", "prize");
        plate.append(prize);

        let label = document.createElement("label");
        label.setAttribute("for", "prize");
        label.innerHTML = parseFloat(category.content[i].price).toFixed(2)+"€";
        prize.append(label);

        column.append(plate);
      }

    }
   }
 }
}
```

Como veis muchísimo código repetido, muchísimas líneas innecesarias, pero me pongo a pensar y acabo teniendo soluciones similares y es porque no tiene una estructura similar, sino muchas variables.
¿Cómo podría hacer esta iteración si quiero que me quede una estructura tan rara?

¡Gracias de antebrazo!

Comment: Te recomendaría el uso de objetos y el patrón de diseño Factoría para manejar la creación de los objetos. Después podrías identificar el objeto (por clase o categoria) y tener una implementación front para cada objeto

Comment: Pero al final me toparía con el mismo problema, y es la forma de implementar los bucles. Si mi problema son los bucles, me gustaría hacerlo de tal forma que no se me mezclase la información, pero no tengo manera de hacerlo (sin hacerlo a lo guarro, quiero decir)